# What would prevent navigator.setAppBadge() from working on Android PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, badge

A PWA I'm working on is no longer showing app badges. It's always been flaky, but somewhere in the last few months it's stopped altogether, although I don't think the related calls have actually changed. I must have done something wrong, but can't find it...  https://theatrehub.online

I've so far checked:

- the PWA successfully installs
- display is set to "standalone" in the manifest
- navigator.setAppBadge is indeed supported on the device and browsers I'm testing
- a service-worker sw.js is present and registers/activates
- sw.js registers a periodic-sync, which every so often triggers a function to fetch the message-count from our API, which then runs `navigator.setAppBadge(msgCount)` with the result.
- Permissions on my Android 13 phone for the PWA set to "Notifications Allowed: Badge,  Lock Screen, and Popup"

However, I can't get any badge showing up on the PWA icon on my phone, despite there definitely being a msgCount number returned...
I've tried connecting via USB remote DevTools and triggered the API-fetching command manually, and even running `navigator.setAppBadge(3)` from the PWA's console in either Top or sw.js context, but it still doesn't add the badge.
I've tried via the newest Chrome and Edge on 2 different phones now...

What aspect of this setup would be preventing the badge from appearing? Is there a different way I should be calling it (either from the service-worker or elsewhere)? How can I better test it manually?

Thank you!
David

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/setAppBadge#browser_compatibility

Shouldn't work at all on Android according to the docs (scroll down to browser compatibility). Interesting.